# integrate vivotek ip camera in C# windows application using VitaminCtrl

Tags: camera, ip

i develop a application to get video from **`vivotek ip camera`** the code is given below but it shows connecting to 10.60.13.12... video is not received

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using VITAMINDECODERLib;

using AxVITAMINDECODERLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {

        public Form1()

        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void btnconnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string strPreIP = "http://";

            if (txtip.TextLength != 0)
                axVitaminCtrl1.Url = strPreIP + txtip.Text;

            // Port
            axVitaminCtrl1.HttpPort = Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text);

            // User name
            if (txtusername.TextLength != 0)
                axVitaminCtrl1.UserName = txtusername.Text;

            // Password
            if (txtpass.TextLength != 0)
                axVitaminCtrl1.Password = txtpass.Text;

            // View stream
            axVitaminCtrl1.ViewStream = (VITAMINDECODERLib.EDualStreamOption)comboviewstream.SelectedIndex.GetHashCode();

            // Protocol
            axVitaminCtrl1.ConnectionProtocol = (VITAMINDECODERLib.EConnProtocol)comboprotocol.SelectedIndex.GetHashCode() + 1;

            axVitaminCtrl1.Connect();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVitaminCtrl1.Disconnect();
        }

        private void comboviewstream_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVitaminCtrl1.ViewStream = (VITAMINDECODERLib.EDualStreamOption)((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex.GetHashCode();
        }

        private void axVitaminCtrl1_OnVideoCodec(object sender, _IVitaminCtrlEvents_OnVideoCodecEvent e)
        {
            e.eVideoCodec = VITAMINDECODERLib.EVideoCodecType.eViCodecMJpeg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check debug/release platform (change it to x86)
2. Your pc that run this program and the camera should have same subnet